# Catching OperationCanceledException faill the second time I run the Task

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

Catching OperationCanceledException faill the second time I run the Task.

The code is this:

```
        private IProgress<long>? _progress = null;
    private double _timeOutMinutes = 5;
    private CancellationTokenSource? _cts = default;

    public FormActualizar(string versionApp)
    {
        _versionApp = versionApp;
        _progress = new Progress<long>(ProgressReport);
        InitializeComponent();
    }

 private async void FormActualizar_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            await DownloadStart();
            await DownloadCompleted();
        }
        catch (OperationCanceledException)
        {
            await DownloadCanceled();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            await DownloadError(ex.Message);
        }
    }

private async Task DownloadStart()
    {
        try
        {
            await SetForm();

            if (_cts != null) _cts.Dispose();
            _cts = new CancellationTokenSource();

            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                client.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(_timeOutMinutes);
                using (var file = new FileStream(_instaladorFilePath, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None))
                {
                    await client.DownloadAsync(_downloadUrl, file, _progress, _cts.Token);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }

public static class HttpClientExtensions
{
    public static async Task DownloadAsync(this HttpClient client, string requestUri, Stream destination, IProgress<long>? progress = null, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
    {
        try
        {
            using (var response = await client.GetAsync(requestUri, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead))
            {
                var contentLength = response.Content.Headers.ContentLength;

                using (var download = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync())
                {
                    if (progress == null || !contentLength.HasValue)
                    {
                        await download.CopyToAsync(destination);
                        return;
                    }
                    await download.CopyToAsync(destination, contentLength.Value, 81920, progress, cancellationToken);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
}

 public static class StreamExtensions
{
    public static async Task CopyToAsync(this Stream source, Stream destination, long length, int bufferSize, IProgress<long>? progress = null, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
    {
        try
        {
            if (source == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(source));
            if (!source.CanRead)
                throw new ArgumentException("Has to be readable", nameof(source));
            if (destination == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(destination));
            if (!destination.CanWrite)
                throw new ArgumentException("Has to be writable", nameof(destination));
            if (bufferSize < 0)
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(bufferSize));

            var buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
            long totalBytesRead = 0;
            int bytesRead = 0;
            while ((bytesRead = await source.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false)) != 0)
            {
                cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
                await destination.WriteAsync(buffer, 0, bytesRead, cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);
                totalBytesRead += bytesRead;
                long porcentaje = ((100 * totalBytesRead / length));
                progress?.Report(porcentaje);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
}

 private async void btnStartStop_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (btnStartStop.Text == "Cancelar")
        {
            _cts?.Cancel();
            _cts?.Dispose();
        }
        else
        {
            await DownloadStart();
        }
    }
```

And the first time I cancel is working good, but the second time I call the DownloadStart(), it first catch the OperationCanceledException, but after that it throw an unhandler error.

I dont get it. Why?

I give you an image of that error:

https://i.ibb.co/Np74XMb/cts.png

Comment: `catch (Exception) { throw; }` - serves no purpose in the above example.

Comment: If throwing the unhandler exception when I run it outside of VS (https://i.ibb.co/Np7ck2S/exception.png)
The mistery is why the first time I cancel it doesnt throw this unhandler exception but the second time yes.

Comment: No. Take a look to the question again, I add all the code.
FormActualizar_Shown() is an event from WinFormsApp. And see that I use "static methods", I dont know if that can help to think about this mistery error.

Comment: I can't see where you are actually calling `CancellationTokenSource.Cancel()`.

Comment: Sorry, I add that at the bottom, and in the top I put how I declare the variables.

Comment: In your `btnStartStop_Click`, wrap `await DownloadStart();` with a `try-catch(OperationCanceledException) { ... }`

Comment: Lol. I'm ashamed. Solved.

Answer (score 0):

I just missed that I need to make a:

```
try{
  ...
}
catch(OperationCanceledException) { ... }
```

outside the await `DownloadStart()`; like in the `form_shown()`.

Solved.

Comment: Consider adding a _"plug"_ for my suggestion. ;)

Comment: I can't, I'm new.